# Changing the color of an item in the listbox to Red

Tags: vb.net

```vb
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        For i = 0 To 5
            Actions.Items.Add("Added Action" & i) ' Actions is list box
        Next

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        For i = 0 To 5
            Errors.Items.Add("Added Error" & i) 'Errors is list box
            If i = 5 Then
                'change the font color to red
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
End class
```

Here one of the item colour of my error list box colour has to be changed and other item colours should be black which is the default. I don't want to use drawitem event handler since it is affecting the performance. Is there any other way to directly change the colour of one of the items of list box. Maybe Xml?

Comment: Use a ListView instead of a ListBox.

Comment: Can you please explain me with an example?

Comment: Well, add a ListView to the Form, add an Item and you'll see that the new Item has a `ForeColor` property. You can change this color to any other color whenever you need to.

Comment: `I don't want to use drawitem event handler since it is affecting the performance.`  There shouldn't be a performance hit.

Answer (score 0):

`ListView` sounds like a good alternative. However, if you must use a `ListBox`, then you must use the [ListBox.DrawItem Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.drawitem?view=netframework-4.8) to color individual lines. In this case, you will need to draw each item manually with code.

```vb
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ' this must be set to be make the DrawItem event fire
    Errors.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    For i = 0 To 5
        Actions.Items.Add("Added Action" & i) ' Actions is list box
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    For i = 0 To 5
        Errors.Items.Add("Added Error" & i) 'Errors is list box
        ' don't worry about coloring here, the logic is in the DrawItem event handler
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Errors_DrawItem(sender As Object, e As DrawItemEventArgs) Handles Errors.DrawItem
    Dim g = e.Graphics
    Dim c = If(e.Index Mod 6 = 5, Color.Red, Color.White)
    e.DrawBackground()
    g.FillRectangle(New SolidBrush(c), e.Bounds)
    e.DrawFocusRectangle()
    g.DrawString(
        DirectCast(sender, ListBox).Items(e.Index).ToString(),
        e.Font,
        New SolidBrush(e.ForeColor),
        New Point(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y))
End Sub
```

[image]

According to your example, every sixth item is colored red (0 to 5, item 5). Repeatedly clicking Button2 will cause 6 items to be added every time, and your logic always colored item 5. For this reason, I test the condition `Index Mod 6 = 5`. Your example may have been simplified, but this is all the information I have. I hope you can make it work!

I thought this sounded [familiar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47269380/832052)... see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47269918/832052).

Comment: I had tried with listview and it is working fine.. Thanks for the help